# How to resize image in css so it keeps proportions (and be cropped)?

Tags: css

- image should have 100% of width (of its container: container is 250px)

  - image should have fixed height of 150px
  - image should keep propotions (so be cropped)

```css
.pic {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:250px; background-color:red">
<img class="pic" src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg">
</div>
```

Problem is : it does not keep propotions. I want the image to be cropped to keep proportions.

Comment: How can the image have a fixed height of 150px AND be 100% the width of its container (250px) if those aren't it's natural dimensions?

Comment: that's why image should be CROPPED : a part of it will be hidden

Comment: Cropped how? In width or height?

Comment: depends on.. the original size of the image of course !

Answer (score 0):

```
.pic { width: 250px; } 
div { overflow:hidden }
```

This will get you the cropped look you want.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the size of the image you should only use `width` property.

[max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) is a good way to avoid over flatted image.

to crop the image you can use `clip` like:
 `clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);`

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_clip)

Find below an example with div cropping with only `height` and `width`.

```css
.pic {
    width:150px;
   
}
.center-cropped {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
#Resize
<div  style="width:250px; background-color:red">
<img class="pic" src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg">
</div>

#Cropped 

<div class="center-cropped"  style="background-image: url('http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg');"  >
```

Comment: `clip` only works on absolutely positioned elements and is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using bleeding-edge stuff, and don't need IE/EDGE support  support right now, you can use a `clip-path`. Size the width of the `img` to `100%`, then clip to a polygon the shape you want.

Here I use top left (`0 0`), top right (`100% 0`), 150 pixels down from top right (`100% 150px`) and 150 pixels down from top left (`0 150px`):

```css
.pic {
  width:100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 150px, 0 150px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 150px, 0 150px);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:250px; height:170px; background-color:red">
<img class="pic" src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg">
</div>
```

Note that current versions of Chrome and Safari require the `-webkit-` prefix. More details on browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Note also that I added a `height` to the `div` - without it, the div sizes itself to the height of the resized image, ignoring the crop.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution, your image and 3 more, nicely packed in a flexbox container. Different sizes => equal to, less and greater than 250x150.

Read the comments in the snippet. I think the code meets all your requirements.

Let me know if it doesn't.

```css
/* generic globals */
html, body                  { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; width: 100%;
                              margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; cursor: default }
*, *:before, *:after        { box-sizing: inherit }

body { 
    display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; /* flexbox container */
    justify-content: center;        /* center content */
    max-width: 82%; margin: 0 auto; /* center on screen */
    background: #fafafa
}

.pic-wrap { /* thumbnail container */
    width: 250px;                   /* as per requirement */
    min-width: 250px;               /* to be inherited by .pic */
    height: 250px;                  /* just for proof, remove when done */
    background: cornflowerblue;     /* ditto?? */
    margin: 4px
}
.pic { /* thumbnail */
    height: 150px;                  /* as per requirement */
    min-height: 150px;              /* for shorter than 150px pics */
    min-width: inherit;             /* for smaller than 250px pics */
    overflow: hidden                /* chop excess */
}
.fit { /* stretcher */
    min-width: inherit;             /* for smaller pics */
    max-width: 100%                 /* no wider than parent width (250px)*/
}
.byline { /* demo */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="byline">574x710 crop</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="fit" src="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="byline">574x710 crop-fit</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/250/200?image=859" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">250x200 crop</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="fit" src="https://unsplash.it/250/150?image=859" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">250x150 match</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/150?image=225" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">150x150 original</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="fit" src="https://unsplash.it/150?image=225" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">150x150 scale-fit</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100?image=076" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">100x100 original</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrap">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="fit" src="https://unsplash.it/100?image=076" />
    </div>
    <div class="byline">100x100 scale-fit</div>
</div>
```